# Как правильно? В первом кругу ада или круге?

Tags: выбор-слов

Как правильно? В в первом кругу ада или в круге

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встречаются оба варианта письма, но более предпочтительным представляется  вариант ***в первом круге ада***.

Как известно, современный предложный падеж включает в себя окончания двух падежей: основное окончание Е **объектного**, или изъяснительного, падежа и вариантное окончание У/Ю местного, или **обстоятельственного**, падежа.

Окончание Е используется по следующим причинам:

1. Это скорее **объектное** (не обстоятельственное) значение. Круг ада — это часть системы наказания в религии, ее определенный **уровень**. Так, 1-й круг называется Лимб; вид наказания — безбольная скорбь; томящиеся — некрещёные младенцы и добродетельные нехристиане.

У Солженицына есть роман "В круге первом" (о тяжелых испытаниях, переносное значение).

2. В современном языке используется термин "в первом круге" для обозначения **этапов** спортивного соревнования.
3. Это книжная речь.

Пример:

По Данту, **в первом круге ада** Господня милость велика: Не боль там за грехи награда, А только вечная тоска.

Comment: Да, удаляем....